# Named parameters in asp.net mvc 5 SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

I have a big nasty SQL query to run in asp.net mvc 5, it's supposed to return a non-db-table object, and needs to be parameterized.

viz.

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyObject>("select a, b from table where a = @par")
```

where I can pass in the value of `@par` as a parameter

```
class MyObject {
  public a {get;set;}
  public b {get;set;}
}
```

For whatever reason the msdn docs assume that one cannot possibly want to execute any but the simplest of queries... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
var myPar = 1;
```

To use a parameter, try:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyObject>("select a, b from table where a = @par", new SqlParameter("par", myPar));
```

Or:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyObject>("select a, b from table where a = {0}", myPar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use SQL select strings to avoid potential SQL injection attacks. You can do this through Linq syntax:

```
 context.Database.table
     .Where(x => x.a == myPar)
     .Select(x => new MyObject { a = x.a, b = x.b });
```